# signTypedData_v4

Tags: signature, multisignature, eip712

I'm using web3j library
i want to sign a structured message butmy code return wrong signature
(my code work for signTypedData_v3 and return currect signature)
but how can i modify my code to can sign signTypedData_v4 messages ?

```
fun main() {
        //  private key
        val privateKey = "0...
    
        // Message data
        val message = """
           {"types":{"EIP712Domain":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"version","type":"string"},{"name":"chainId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"verifyingContract","type":"address"}],"OrderComponents":[{"name":"offerer","type":"address"},{"name":"zone","type":"address"},{"name":"offer","type":"OfferItem[]"},{"name":"consideration","type":"ConsiderationItem[]"},{"name":"orderType","type":"uint8"},{"name":"startTime","type":"uint256"},{"name":"endTime","type":"uint256"},{"name":"zoneHash","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"salt","type":"uint256"},{"name":"conduitKey","type":"bytes32"},{"name":"counter","type":"uint256"}],"OfferItem":[{"name":"itemType","type":"uint8"},{"name":"token","type":"address"},{"name":"identifierOrCriteria","type":"uint256"},{"name":"startAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"endAmount","type":"uint256"}],"ConsiderationItem":[{"name":"itemType","type":"uint8"},{"name":"token","type":"address"},{"name":"identifierOrCriteria","type":"uint256"},{"name":"startAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"endAmount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"recipient","type":"address"}]},"primaryType":"OrderComponents","domain":{"name":"Seaport","version":"1.5","chainId":"137","verifyingContract":"0x00000000000000ADc04C56Bf30aC9d3c0aAF14dC"},"message":{"offerer":"0x54ffab13A4852F81e2feB184918c115604b7bfbA","offer":[{"itemType":"3","token":"0x44b3f42e2BF34F62868Ff9e9dAb7C2F807ba97Cb","identifierOrCriteria":"45","startAmount":"1","endAmount":"1"}],"consideration":[{"itemType":"0","token":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","identifierOrCriteria":"0","startAmount":"925000000000000000","endAmount":"925000000000000000","recipient":"0x54ffab13A4852F81e2feB184918c115604b7bfbA"},{"itemType":"0","token":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","identifierOrCriteria":"0","startAmount":"25000000000000000","endAmount":"25000000000000000","recipient":"0x0000a26b00c1F0DF003000390027140000fAa719"},{"itemType":"0","token":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","identifierOrCriteria":"0","startAmount":"50000000000000000","endAmount":"50000000000000000","recipient":"0x99F1117F13e072b299942037E6A5d1469912B47A"}],"startTime":"1710071322","endTime":"1712749722","orderType":"1","zone":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000","zoneHash":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","salt":"24446860302761739304752683030156737591518664810215442929800495252339539996469","conduitKey":"0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000","totalOriginalConsiderationItems":"3","counter":"0"}}
        """.trimIndent()
    
        // Parse your private key to Credentials
        val credentials = Credentials.create(privateKey)
    
        val hash = StructuredDataEncoder(message).hashStructuredData().clone()
    
        val signature = Sign.signMessage(hash, credentials.ecKeyPair, false)
    
    
    println(Numeric.toHexString(signature.r+signature.s+signature.v))
    
    }
```

Comment: please check the solution below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `totalOriginalConsiderationItems` in the primary message that you pass in to sign, but it is missing in the `types` field:

[image: missing-property-eip-712-signature-kotlin-web3j]

---

**The type and the corresponding values do not match.**

A fixed message with a fixed types object is the following:

```json
{
    "types":{
       "EIP712Domain":[
          {
             "name":"name",
             "type":"string"
          },
          {
             "name":"version",
             "type":"string"
          },
          {
             "name":"chainId",
             "type":"uint256"
          },
          {
             "name":"verifyingContract",
             "type":"address"
          }
       ],
       "OrderComponents":[
          {
             "name":"offerer",
             "type":"address"
          },
          {
             "name":"zone",
             "type":"address"
          },
          {
             "name":"offer",
             "type":"OfferItem[]"
          },
          {
             "name":"consideration",
             "type":"ConsiderationItem[]"
          },
          {
             "name":"orderType",
             "type":"uint8"
          },
          {
             "name":"startTime",
             "type":"uint256"
          },
          {
             "name":"endTime",
             "type":"uint256"
          },
          {
             "name":"zoneHash",
             "type":"bytes32"
          },
          {
             "name":"salt",
             "type":"uint256"
          },
          {
             "name":"conduitKey",
             "type":"bytes32"
          },
          {
            "name": "totalOriginalConsiderationItems",
            "type": "uint128"
          },
          {
             "name":"counter",
             "type":"uint256"
          }
       ],
       "OfferItem":[
          {
             "name":"itemType",
             "type":"uint8"
          },
          {
             "name":"token",
             "type":"address"
          },
          {
             "name":"identifierOrCriteria",
             "type":"uint256"
          },
          {
             "name":"startAmount",
             "type":"uint256"
          },
          {
             "name":"endAmount",
             "type":"uint256"
          }
       ],
       "ConsiderationItem":[
          {
             "name":"itemType",
             "type":"uint8"
          },
          {
             "name":"token",
             "type":"address"
          },
          {
             "name":"identifierOrCriteria",
             "type":"uint256"
          },
          {
             "name":"startAmount",
             "type":"uint256"
          },
          {
             "name":"endAmount",
             "type":"uint256"
          },
          {
             "name":"recipient",
             "type":"address"
          }
       ]
    },
    "primaryType":"OrderComponents",
    "domain":{
       "name":"Seaport",
       "version":"1.5",
       "chainId":"137",
       "verifyingContract":"0x00000000000000ADc04C56Bf30aC9d3c0aAF14dC"
    },
    "message":{
       "offerer":"0x54ffab13A4852F81e2feB184918c115604b7bfbA",
       "offer":[
          {
             "itemType":"3",
             "token":"0x44b3f42e2BF34F62868Ff9e9dAb7C2F807ba97Cb",
             "identifierOrCriteria":"45",
             "startAmount":"1",
             "endAmount":"1"
          }
       ],
       "consideration":[
          {
             "itemType":"0",
             "token":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
             "identifierOrCriteria":"0",
             "startAmount":"925000000000000000",
             "endAmount":"925000000000000000",
             "recipient":"0x54ffab13A4852F81e2feB184918c115604b7bfbA"
          },
          {
             "itemType":"0",
             "token":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
             "identifierOrCriteria":"0",
             "startAmount":"25000000000000000",
             "endAmount":"25000000000000000",
             "recipient":"0x0000a26b00c1F0DF003000390027140000fAa719"
          },
          {
             "itemType":"0",
             "token":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
             "identifierOrCriteria":"0",
             "startAmount":"50000000000000000",
             "endAmount":"50000000000000000",
             "recipient":"0x99F1117F13e072b299942037E6A5d1469912B47A"
          }
       ],
       "startTime":"1710071322",
       "endTime":"1712749722",
       "orderType":"1",
       "zone":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
       "zoneHash":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
       "salt":"24446860302761739304752683030156737591518664810215442929800495252339539996469",
       "conduitKey":"0x0000007b02230091a7ed01230072f7006a004d60a8d4e71d599b8104250f0000",
       "totalOriginalConsiderationItems":"3",
       "counter":"0"
    }
 }
```

---

Hopefully, that solves your problem with Web3j & Kotlin typed v4 signature (`signtypeddata_v4`) signing. :)

---

### (*Edited*)

Does at least signing this simple message work?

```json
{"domain":{"chainId":1,"name":"Ether Mail","verifyingContract":"0xCcCCccccCCCCcCCCCCCcCcCccCcCCCcCcccccccC","version":"1"},"message":{"contents":"Hello, Bob!","attachedMoneyInEth":4.2,"from":{"name":"Cow","wallets":["0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826","0xDeaDbeefdEAdbeefdEadbEEFdeadbeEFdEaDbeeF"]},"to":[{"name":"Bob","wallets":["0xbBbBBBBbbBBBbbbBbbBbbbbBBbBbbbbBbBbbBBbB","0xB0BdaBea57B0BDABeA57b0bdABEA57b0BDabEa57","0xB0B0b0b0b0b0B000000000000000000000000000"]}]},"primaryType":"Mail","types":{"EIP712Domain":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"version","type":"string"},{"name":"chainId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"verifyingContract","type":"address"}],"Group":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"members","type":"Person[]"}],"Mail":[{"name":"from","type":"Person"},{"name":"to","type":"Person[]"},{"name":"contents","type":"string"}],"Person":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"wallets","type":"address[]"}]}}
```

*P.S. It'll help better understand where the problem lies.*

Please try it.

---

*(Edit):*

Here's how you can do that with server-side NodeJS, *considering you have an Ethereum private key*, and with a server-side (NPM) `@metamask/eth-sig-util` package:

```js
const { signTypedData, SignTypedDataVersion } = require("@metamask/eth-sig-util");

const signatureResult = signTypedData({
version: SignTypedDataVersion.V4,
data: {"domain":{"chainId":1,"name":"Ether Mail","verifyingContract":"0xCcCCccccCCCCcCCCCCCcCcCccCcCCCcCcccccccC","version":"1"},"message":{"contents":"Hello, Bob!","attachedMoneyInEth":4.2,"from":{"name":"Cow","wallets":["0xCD2a3d9F938E13CD947Ec05AbC7FE734Df8DD826","0xDeaDbeefdEAdbeefdEadbEEFdeadbeEFdEaDbeeF"]},"to":[{"name":"Bob","wallets":["0xbBbBBBBbbBBBbbbBbbBbbbbBBbBbbbbBbBbbBBbB","0xB0BdaBea57B0BDABeA57b0bdABEA57b0BDabEa57","0xB0B0b0b0b0b0B000000000000000000000000000"]}]},"primaryType":"Mail","types":{"EIP712Domain":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"version","type":"string"},{"name":"chainId","type":"uint256"},{"name":"verifyingContract","type":"address"}],"Group":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"members","type":"Person[]"}],"Mail":[{"name":"from","type":"Person"},{"name":"to","type":"Person[]"},{"name":"contents","type":"string"}],"Person":[{"name":"name","type":"string"},{"name":"wallets","type":"address[]"}]}},
privateKey: BigInt(`0xd9518676d87bc64f9e43f6ad0fdaedac08eaf8ad49361f586b0887d001b4978e`)
});

console.log({signatureResult});
```

**The output result is:**

```bash
$ node index.js
{
  signatureResult: '0x8abc89d7ff51e002e24de76507418210632d1fc27c10e9677c2ccd9c6d37c7ff5f6442ae375d3623b0
bf2ad1d610ab3bb7e7106286677b56e43d8d694441ca6f1c'
}
```

---

### As you can see, if the property in the filled values is not specified in the types field of the message to sign, then an error will be thrown:

```bash
node_modules\@metamask\eth-sig-util\dist\sign-typed-data.js:150
throw new Error(`missing value for field ${name} of type ${type}`);
```

Comment: i got this message from opnsea.io , i can't change it...

Comment: Why not edit the `types:OrderComponents` struct's field though?

Comment: You cannot edit the data, but *you can edit the type specification*, considering it doesn't match with the data

Comment: I did this but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: i got this signature :
`0x8abc89d7ff51e002e24de76507418210632d1fc27c10e9677c2ccd9c6d37c7ff5f6442ae375d3623b0bf2ad1d610ab3bb7e7106286677b56e43d8d694441ca6f1c`

with this private key :
`0xd9518676d87bc64f9e43f6ad0fdaedac08eaf8ad49361f586b0887d001b4978e`
but i don't know it's okay or not....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152036/discussion-between-luntik-and-mila-a).

Comment: @luntik, please accept my answer *if it was helpful* :)